# How can I make my self signed certificate trusted?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, postman

I am trying to test my controller methods for a asp.net web api site I deployed on IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2. But postman returns this response. I don't want to buy a certificate. This is only for test purposes after all. Can I make my self signed certificate trusted? If not, is the a way around this so I could test my web api methods on postman?

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred while sending the request.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at TetherThingWS.Controllers.AccountController.<LoginUser>d__12.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Net.WebException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)",
    "InnerException": {
      "Message": "An error has occurred.",
      "ExceptionMessage": "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.",
      "ExceptionType": "System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException",
      "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to buy one, you can get free ones from let's encrypt.

Comment: I think for test purposes it is enough to just add the public key of your self-signed certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities on the consuming client where you use Postman (Works for Windows, I guess there is a similar solution for Linux).

Comment: Let's encrypt runs on Unix-based operating systems. I am working on windows server

Comment: Postman has a blog post about how to make self signed certificates work - http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/